# fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x21E00D

Tags: c++, sass, nodes, node-gyp, gyp

I am new to node,
I have node version 8.6. Whenever I try to build this particular app which I cloned from git which a tutorial tutor built and his was working, I get this error. I have tried all I can think of but this error persist whenever I run the npm install command

```
C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\.node-gyp\8.6.0\x64\node.lib : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at
 0x21E00D [C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj" (default t
argets) -- FAILED.

Done Building Project "C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (
default targets) -- FAILED.

Done Building Project "C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default targe
ts) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/GR-' with '/GR' [C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\n
ode-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
  cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/GR-' with '/GR' [C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\n
ode-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
  cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/GR-' with '/GR' [C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\n
ode-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
  cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/GR-' with '/GR' [C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\n
ode-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
  cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/GR-' with '/GR' [C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\n
ode-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
  ..\..\src\libsass\src\json.cpp(26): warning C4005: '_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE': macro redefinition [C:\xampp\htdocs\n
odejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
  ..\..\src\libsass\src\sass2scss.cpp(9): warning C4005: '_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE': macro redefinition [C:\xampp\htdo
cs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
  cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/GR-' with '/GR' [C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\n
ode-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]


"C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj" (default target) (4) ->
  ..\src\binding.cpp(140): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'double', possible loss of data [C:\x
ampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\nan\nan_new.h(208): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from '
size_t' to 'double', possible loss of data (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\list.cpp) [C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\o
fflineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\nan\nan_new.h(208): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from '
size_t' to 'double', possible loss of data (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\map.cpp) [C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\of
flineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]


"C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj" (default target) (4) ->
(Link target) ->
  C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\.node-gyp\8.6.0\x64\node.lib : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read
at 0x21E00D [C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]

    11 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:04:58.47
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\nodejs\\offlineweb\\wittr\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bufferutil@1.2.1 (node_modules\bufferutil):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: utf-8-validate@1.2.2 (node_modules\utf-8-validate):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: utf-8-validate@1.2.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-29T22_55_33_341Z-debug.log
```

Pls your suggestions will highly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an extensive research, I created an issue in github, where I cloned the test app from. This solution was suggested and it worked for me. 
https://github.com/jakearchibald/wittr/issues/27

Answer (score -1):

I also found [this helpful comment](https://github.com/nwjs/nw-gyp/issues/63#issuecomment-77660581). 
After installing Python 2.7 and Visual C++ Build Tools I deleted node_modules folder, opened CMD from Administrator and ran `npm install --msvs_version=2015`. And it installed successfully!

[This link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows) helped me to install Python and VS C++ build tools.